# Oracle: How can I set up the example tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

Many Oracle discussions use the **emp** and related tables in the **scott/tiger** schema.  How can I set up these example tables on my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL for setting up the demo tables can be found here:

> http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/sql_plus/htdocs/demobld.html

If you have access to your Oracle server directories they can also be found here:

> $oracle_home/sqlplus/demo